# Create multiple views in Gmail based on label criteria

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Is there a way to create a readily accessible view in Gmail based on labels you specify?

Based on [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62881/exclude-label-from-a-gmail-search) and [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10581/filtering-based-on-multiple-labels-in-gmail), I am aware that I can do `label:Business1 OR Invoice AND NOT label:MyBadLabel1`

However, I manage many business accounts so it becomes a hassle to manually type these in each time I need to search for something:

1. `label:Business1 OR Invoice AND NOT label:MyBadLabel1` or
2. `label:Business2 OR Invoice AND NOT label:MyBadLabel1` or
3. `label:Business3 OR Invoice AND NOT label:MyBadLabel1`

The [Multiple Inbox](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9694882?hl=en) feature in Gmail seems to do the trick but it is limited to 5 inbox views only. Is there a way to do what I need in a more scalable manner?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you considered to save each view in your browser bookmarks?

Comment: @Rubén oh wow that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!